# Postfix cannot find a MySQL shared library

Tags: arch-linux, mysql, dynamic-linking, postfix

I am trying to install Postfix with MySQL support. When I start or run the postfix daemon, it complains that it "cannot find libmysqlclient.so.18", which is in the directory `/usr/local/mysql/lib`, which I linked when I built the package.

I added a symlink to `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18` in `/usr/lib`, which fixed the problem, but that's a really kludgy solution and I'd rather do it the right way.

I followed [this documentation](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html), and it works except for that small error.

I am running Arch Linux, kernel version 2.6.33

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to install MySQL from its Arch Linux package, and then the library would be in `/usr/lib` and everything would work smoothly.

If you're installing MySQL outside the packaging system, then `/usr/local/lib` is the expected location for libraries; put a symbolic link there. I recommend using stow or xstow to automatically create symbolic links when installing programs from source; see [Keeping track of programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs/16397#16397).

If you want all programs to look for libraries in `/usr/local/mysql/lib`, add it to the default library search path in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. But I rather recommend a symbolic link in `/usr/local/lib`, if that's what you want.

If you only want Postfix to look for libraries in `/usr/local/mysql/lib`, edit the script that launches Postfix — something like `/etc/rc.d/postfix` (I don't know the exact location on Arch). Before the postfix daemon is started, add the line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}/usr/local/mysql/lib"
```

Comment: Installing MySQL with pacman makes sense. Unfortunately, pacman is broken.

Placing a symlink in `usr/local/lib` (instead of `/usr/lib` like I did) would be good. I was just wondering why this was something the user has to do; that's something that could be automated fairly easily. Perhaps it's an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux I recently had a similar issue with installing libraries from custom builds.  In my case it installed the libraries to /usr/local/lib.  Running an application which needed this library resulted in a similar runtime error: can't locate the library.   (*Wouldn't life be easier on a BSD System?* :-D )

The proper solution is to add the new local library directory into the runtime linker path.  **On Arch Linux**, this seems to be:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf
```

So to add your new library path,

```
sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf
```

then append the path on a new line:

```
/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

In my case, my /etc/ld.conf.so file now looks like the below, because I added /usr/local/lib:

```
#
# /etc/ld.so.conf
#

include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib

# End of file
```

Verify this is correct my using:

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Your custom libraries should be listed, i.e. they are "found" by the linker.

To get more info on this configuration file and the runtime linker,

```
man ldconfig
```

It seems Arch Linux is set up to use a custom directory with multiple config files (/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf) however that's too much SYSV for me and is complete overkill; just add the new paths to /etc/ld.so.conf.