# A window disappeared after I pressed a key in Openbox, how do I bring it back?

Tags: window-manager, openbox, window-management, parted-magic

I had Firefox running, then (possibly) as a result of a key combination I don't recall, it quickly vanished from screen and Task Bar/Window List.
From my [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/what-does-the-interruptible-sleep-state-indicate) it was established the issue is likely that I made the window disappear, though it isn't on either of the two user-displayable desktops.

I am running the Openbox Window Manager on Parted Magic. I don't have tools such as `wmctrl` or `xdotool` installed/available, which I understand have the ability to bring the window back to the current desktop, unhide, unshade, or maximize it.

Does anyone know if Openbox exposes this fuctionality natively, or any other way to perform the same with Openbox built-in tools / ones that can be added/used with this distro?

Comment: Can you not install either xdotool or wmctrl then?

Comment: I understand that I would have to compile sources of these tools, in order to get them to use in the current session, something I have had 0 hours of experience with. So, on [Gilles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885) [advice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/#comment147020_96802) thought I would ask the above, first, just in case.

Comment: What distro is this?

Comment: As this is the second time it has been missed in my questions, I have/will try to, put a link to it in my question/s :)

Comment: I saw the other Q and figured it was that but wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on a large number of things, it might be that you have iconified the window. If you are running a standard OpenBox configuration then middle click on the background (aka root window) and it should bring up a menu of top level windows on each of the desktops. Some of these entries will be dim, and in round brackets `()`. These are in iconified state, select them to return them to normal state.