# How does Linux operating system shut down?

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown, init

Gilles wrote an excellent reply about how Linux kernel shuts down at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122667/674

I was wondering how Linux OS shuts down  (in cases of both systemvinit and systemd)? I am expecting something similar to the boot sequence of Linux OS.
I am particularly wondering how the processes notify each other, by some signal like SIGTERM and SIGKILL, or some other interprocess communication way?

Thanks.

Related:

[What is the difference between "when the operating system shuts down" and "when the kernel shuts down"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489609/what-is-the-difference-between-when-the-operating-system-shuts-down-and-when)

[When the operating system shuts down, how does a service manager know that it should sends SIGTERM and SIGKILL to its services?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489610/when-the-operating-system-shuts-down-how-does-a-service-manager-know-that-it-sh)

Comment: Maybe at a high level with only critical parts?

Comment: Don't be afraid. Since you mentioned it, I would refrain myself from doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With both `sysvinit` and systemd, shutting the operating system down starts by notifying the `init` process (the process with pid 1) that the system should shut down (or reboot, or power off).

`sysvinit` does this by using the `/run/initctl` FIFO to communicate with `init`, asking it to switch to the corresponding runlevel. See [the `init` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sysvinit-core/init.8#INTERFACE) for a brief overview.

systemd supports a variety of ways to do this. Various [signals](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#Signals) can be used to request a shutdown, reboot, etc., in various flavours; it’s also possible to request this over d-bus ([the `busctl` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html) explains how to explore that).

Once pid 1 has been asked to shut down, it follows its configuration and specification and goes through all the appropriate steps for it. This typically includes notifying all users that a shutdown is in progress, shutting down all the running services (in a managed way with systemd; using shutdown scripts in various forms with `sysvinit`), syncing the mounted file systems, possibly unmounting them, killing all remaining processes (with the usual `TERM` then `KILL` sequence), and finally calling the kernel’s `reboot` system call with the appropriate parameters.

This describes the general sequence. There are many more twists to all this, including access control (with Polkit), various available hooks, `kexec`, sudden power-off handling, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> handling... The systemd documentation covers many of these details.

Comment: Thanks. In https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sysvinit-core/init.8.en.html#SIGNALS, `init` also reacts to some signals. Does that mean we can communicate with `init` by sending some signals instead of using FIFO, asking it to switch to the corresponding runlevel?

Comment: `/run/initctl` is FIFO not socket. Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use certain signals to communicate with `sysvinit`’s `init`, but none of them are relevant here. You can’t use them to request an arbitrary runlevel change.