# Is it possible to distinguish signal from kernel at reboot and at kill from terminal

Tags: process, kill, signals, shutdown, reboot

As I know, we can send a signal `SIGTERM` to a process by pressing `ctrl+c` or by using `pkill -f processName`.

Also, when we `reboot` or `shutdown`, the kernel will send `SIGTERM` to each process too.

So I'm asking if we could distinguish these two cases? (as they are all `SIGTERM`, we can't distinguish them by the signal)

Maybe the kernel provides us some kind of API? such as `bool isRebooting()` or `bool isShutdown()`?

Comment: No, [the kernel doesn’t send `SIGTERM`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486366/86440), the shutdown procedure does. What init system and/or service manager are you using?

Comment: "shutdown" is a userspace concept, not a kernel one.  The init system (sysvinit, systemd, upstart,....) will be doing all this work.

Comment: what unix system sends a TERM signal when you mash control+c? more typical is an INT signal...