# How to make a process in T (trace) state in Linux?

Tags: linux, process

According to [What does the “interruptible sleep” state indicate?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96797/what-does-the-interruptible-sleep-state-indicate)
 there is a state called "T".

I tried to run a python script with `strace` but `/proc/pid/stat` still showed the the process was in `S`, waiting on `do_wait` (`cat /proc/6145/wchan    -> do_wait`)

```
def f():
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    print(1)

f()
```

Comment: T state means the process is being traced, not tracing others

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克I tried looking at `stat` of the program being traced (python script), still under `S`. Not `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have `T` mixed up with `t`. From [`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

```
               T    stopped by job control signal
               t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
```

Anyway, to put a process in state `T` (stopped), `kill -STOP` its PID, or hit Ctrl+Z while it's running in the terminal. To put a process in state `t` (being traced), attach to it with ptrace, but don't let it continue like strace does. One way to do this is run `gdb`, then `attach` to its PID.

Comment: strace is using `PTRACE_SEIZE`, and simply `gdb -p PID` will work.

Comment: Thank you very much!!