# Add multiple subdirectories under the same parent directory to PATH

Tags: path

I have installed some tools and put it under $HOME/tools/ and each tool has its own /bin directory that contains the executable program. I now have the path to each individual /bin in my $HOME/.bashrc file like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tools/tool1/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tools/tool2/bin
...
```

I'm wondering if it's OK to write the following for all the tools?

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tools
```

If it doesn't work, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You don't need the export, `PATH` is already marked for export and will be put into child process' environments.

Comment: OK, I see. I saw many people still use export..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a directory to `PATH` only makes the executables in this directory available as bare command names. This does not extend to subdirectories.

You can put a loop in your `.profile` ([not `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)) to add multiple directories, for example:

```
for d in ~/tools/*/bin; do
  PATH="$PATH:$d"
done
```

(You don't need to repeat `export`: when a variable is exported, it stays exported, and modifications are reflected in the environment).

If you create new directories under `tools`, this will not be reflected in your ongoing session, only the next time `.profile` is read. If this is not satisfactory, you can use a different approach: put a single directory such as `~/bin` in your PATH, and when you install software, create symbolic links in `~/bin`. [Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) (or its alternative [XStow](http://xstow.sourceforge.net/)) is a good way of doing this; see [Keeping track of programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs/16397#16397) for an overview of how this works.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I wanted to vote for your answer but don't have enough reputation to do that yet...

Comment: I tried Stow and it's pretty cool. I do have a question on the link you mentioned. In your example, the executables were installed in /usr/local/stow/PROGRAM_NAME/bin and if you just issue "stow PROGRAM_NAME", all the subdirectories under /usr/local/stow/PROGRAM_NAME are also linked and in our server it looks like bin -> stow/PROGRAM_NAME/bin. However, when I tried to include /usr/local/stow in the $PATH, the executable in stow/PROGRAM_NAME/bin actually can be invoked. Based on what people said here, this is contradictory as bin->stow/PROGRAM_NAME/bin is a subdirectory now, right?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you did. There wouldn't be any executable in `/usr/local/stow`, but they are linked in `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH, that's where they're found.

Comment: i read the GNU manual and my understanding is that stow can apply to a package directory, not a single executable. And "the subdirectory is created within the target, and its contents are symlinked, rather than just creating a symlink for the directory" so that's what I saw.. link is here http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html

Comment: i came up with my way of dealing with subdirectory under PROGRAM_NAME, if the program already has a /bin directory, I just stow that PROGRAM_NAME/bin directory. Otherwise, I create a /bin directory and symlink myself all the executables I need, and then stow the new PROGRAM_NAME/bin directory. This seem to work best for me and not worry about using --ignore to get rid of many things I don't want to be stowed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding things to the `$PATH` is not recursive. Only the directories that are present in `$PATH` will be searched by your shell when it's looking for executables to run.

To see what's currently on your `$PATH`:

```
$ printenv PATH
```

4 common tactics when dealing with many directories such as you're facing is to either:

1. add them individually, which is perfectly fine, `$PATH` can be fairly long.
2. use the command [`alternatives`](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5562/5-minute-guide-to-using-the-alternatives-command-on-fedoracentosrhel/) ([man page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_alternatives.htm)) to create symbolic links to the various executables in the differing directories. This trades a long `$PATH` for having to maintain symbolic links to the various executables.
3. create either aliases or wrapper `.sh` scripts that can exist in a common directory and will dynamically change the `$PATH` or other environment variables as needed.
4. Use a tool to manage your environment such as [`modules`](http://modules.sourceforge.net/).

#### Further background

Where I used to work we used a technology we developed internally called `use` scripts which operators would run commands such as `use X`, where `X` was the name + version of a CAD/CAM software package such as Xilinx. This would automatically add the appropriate directories and environment variables to the user's shell. When they were done with `X` they could say `use -no X`. to unload this tool from their environment.

#### More exotic methods

Another approach for building up your `$PATH` but in a more modular way would be to mimic the way most systems work by creating a `/etc/profile.d` directory. You can make your own, or even utilize your system's `/etc/profile.d` directory to facilitate the adding of things to your environment and/or `$PATH`.

For example, if you look at your `/etc/bashrc` you might notice this construct:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "$PS1" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

You could model yourself something similar where you could put fragments of things you want to get added to your `$PATH` + environment.

When this loop runs it will incorporate the contents of the various files in your version of the `profile.d` directory. You'd just need to create files in your directory with content like this:

*file1.sh*

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tools/tool1/bin
```

*file2.sh*

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/tools/tool2/bin
```

You can organize this directory anyway you want.

Comment: OK. I got that. What would you do to avoid typing out all the directories? Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @user2157668 - where I used to work we actually developed a internal tool similar to [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/). We supported 100's of CAD/CAM applications though. In lieu of doing that I would try parameterize the components as much as possible and then construct the `$PATH` using these variables.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I wanted to vote for your answer but don't have enough reputation to do that yet...

Answer (score 0):

No that will not work ! that will add only $HOME/tools to your path.

The principle of each tool having it's own bin dir doesn't fit well really, think about `/bin` or `/usr/bin` everything goes in there (well nearly everything) each package does not have it's own bin dir. ( Orthogonal ? )

Comment: you mean I can create symbolic links in a $HOME/tools/bin/ directory and link tool1 and tool2 there?

Comment: No, I didn't say that, and that is a good idea. Add to your post to clarify maybe. tks

Comment: I wanted to vote for your answer but don't have enough reputation to do that yet...

Answer (score 0):

You could do either of the following

1. Just add all the bin folders like you have done
2. Create another bin folder such as `$HOME/bin`, and then symbolic link the relevant binaries into `$HOME/bin`, and then add `$HOME/bin` to your path
3. If you have admin rights to the machine, then use `/usr/local` for you application compilations, and then everything be in place automatically, and you don't need to change your path at all. i.e. `./configure` on it's on will automatically make sure that the application will install in `/usr/local`
4. Use something like modules environment http://modules.sourceforge.net/, which then you can add to your environment, and depending the application you want to run, then you can change the environment.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I wanted to vote for your answer but don't have enough reputation to do that yet...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
`export PATH="$PATH:$(du "~/tools/" | cut -f2 | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:*$//')"`
This will add ~/tools itself along with all its subdirectories into $PATH
Explanation:
- `du` will display all the subdirectories info each line
- `cut -f2` will extract the second column, i.e., the names of the subdirectories
- `tr '\n' ':'` will change each link break into a colon. This will join all lines into a single line and the subdirectories are delimited by a colon
- `sed 's/:*$//'` will remove the last colon