# Change the default program installation location?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

I have learn linux recently, but i confused about how linux system works, especially about how linux handle program files, in windows all program is in one directory Programfiles (and some in Windows) but in linux, when i install program automaticly (apt) i think its "randomly" place the program files not in one place (not just programfiles folder).

Can i change DEFAULT place/folder of program in linux? I have linux mint 17.3 64 bit.

Comment: See also [Where should an application be installed if it consists of multiple files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252552/where-should-an-application-be-installed-if-it-consists-of-multiple-files/252580#252580)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: As long as you use the package manager that comes with your Linux distribution, you can't change the place where the binaries are installed. However, the installation paths follow a long-established [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (with minor differences between distributions).

If you build packages on your own you could, in theory, choose the installation prefix yourself, but usually departing from the conventions comes with some kind of penalty (read: It's a bad idea if you don't know exactly what you're doing).

Answer (score 1):

Generally not: most programs on Linux are packages, which *could* be relocatable.  However few are setup to allow relocation.  In particular, systems (such as Mint) derived from Debian do not provide relocatable packages.  RPM-based systems may include some relocatable packages.

Further reading:

- [Relocatable Debian packages (like rpm prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307622/relocatable-debian-packages-like-rpm-prefix)
- [Run time installation directory of debian package contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921626/run-time-installation-directory-of-debian-package-contents)
- [creating relocatable packages with dpkg](https://lists.debian.org/debian-mentors/2004/12/msg00144.html)