# How to install tar file "globally"?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, package-management, tar

I want to install a local tar file in such a way that it's immediately available on the command line, just as if I had used "sudo apt-get install XYZ" (assume there are no dependencies).

I know how to unpack the tar and then compile with configure/make, but that just leaves me with an executable that I have to add a path to later.

I suppose I could copy to /bin and be done with it, but I was just wondering what the standard practice was here.

As a bonus, it would be nice to know how to do this with RPM's and other types of packages as well.

Comment: Does the tar file contain files in various usable paths, such that you could extract it from / and have the binaries land in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin and ditto the man pages and libraries?

Comment: It wasn't really a specific tar I had in mind, just the general case I was wondering about. Not sure if that would be a great idea anyway. I mean, it could possibly clobber a file/directory, couldn't it?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `-C /` is probably easier.

Comment: [Use stow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the program you want to install follows good practice, you can install it with

```
./configure
make
make install
```

`./configure` checks if your system meets all requirements and configures the install options. `make` compiles everything, and `make install` copies all necessary files to the right places. You don't want to do the last step by hand, because it will be quite tedious to get all the libraries, man pages and whatnot to the right place.

You can also define where the packages should be installed. For example, if you want to install a package in your home directory (because e.g. you don't have admin rights), you can use

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME"/somefolder
```

`make install` will then install it to this folder. Usually you won't need this, though.

Comment: Ah, yeah I just tried that with one particular tar I had and it seemed to work as you described. But that "prefix" switch still might come in handy someday, so I'll keep that trick in mind too. Edit: sorry, not enough reps to accept or upvote, but as far as I'm concerned this issue is resolved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should always have enough rep to accept an answer. Otherwise the system would be broken (IMHO). But anyway, glad it works!

Comment: Weird, yeah I can accept it now (still can't upvote, that takes 15 reps apparently).

Comment: Note that if your home directory might have spaces in its name--I've seen this on some macOS systems--then `$HOME` will need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: This is of course true, and it's generally good advice to quote variables in bash. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 8):

*This answer is based on [several chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39776162#39776162) I posted, which now serve as an extended summary.*

#### The `$PATH` Environment Variable

By "immediately available on the command line," I assume you mean that you can run it like `name`, rather than having to type something like `/path/to/name`, such as `/home/galahad/bin/name` or `./name`.

Your [`$PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like) contains a list of `:`-separated directory names. When you run a command in your shell that contains a `/` character, it's interpreted as the exact location and name of an executable to run. But when you run a command that does *not* contain a `/`, your shell searches the directories in `$PATH` for executables by that name, and runs the first one it finds. (It may also remember where executables you've run before are located. So, in practice, it does not have to search them each time.)

This is why `./name` is the common way to run the executable called `name` located in the current directory. Running `name` instead would search the directories in `$PATH`.

If you run `echo "$PATH"` you will see something like this, though it may well not be exactly this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Directories in `$PATH` don't have to be called `bin`, but this is common.

#### Configuring Your Build

When you have source code that is compiled by running `./configure` and `make`, you will usually use `make install` (or `sudo make install`) to install it. This copies files from the build directory into the install location. When the thing you are installing provides executable commands, those executables are typically copied into a directory that is in `$PATH` or that you should consider adding to `$PATH`.

Although building and installing software is often as simple as running `./configure`, `make`, sometimes `make check` or `make test`, and then `make install` or `sudo make install`, you will sometimes want to pass options to the `configure` script to configure the build. In particular, [**as pfnuesel says**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389898/11938), this is how you configure *where* the software is going to be installed. Even though the `make install` step actually installs the software, the locations where everything will be installed are typically established in the `./configure` step.

The most common option for this is `--prefix`. The default prefix, when you don't tell `configure` what to use, is usually `/usr/local`. (Occasionally, a program or library's source code defaults to some other prefix. Fortunately this is rare.)

So `./configure` is usually equivalent to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`. To install software in your home directory, you could use `./configure --prefix=/home/galahad` (if `/home/galahad` is your home directory) or `--prefix="$HOME"`. Then of course you must still build and install the software with `make`. I should say that not all software that is distributed in source code form is built this way. You should always look for documentation inside the extracted source code archive.

#### What `--prefix` Means

When you run `./configure --prefix=directory`, you are indicating that the software should be installed under the *`directory`* directory. But this rarely, if ever, places loose files in *`directory`*. Instead, it places files that serve different purposes in the different subdirectories of *`directory`*. If those subdirectories don't exist, it creates them.

Executables usually go in `directory/bin`, though they may go in `directory/sbin` if they're commonly used for system administration or they may go (more rarely, these days) in `directory/games` if they are games. Libraries go in `directory/lib` or another similarly named directory like `directory/lib32`. Header files go in `directory/include`. Manual pages go in `directory/man`. Data files used by the software go in `directory/share`.

That's what it means for *`directory`* to be a *prefix*. It's the parent directory that contains the locations in which different files will be installed. **It thus appears as a prefix** in the [absolute paths](https://foldoc.org/absolute%20path) of most files and directories created by running `make install` or `sudo make install`.

There are some exceptions to this. Systemwide configuration files--which are sometimes created when installing the software that will use them, though not always--usually go in `/etc`. This is not typically affected by specifying a different prefix. Even if you install a lot of software in `/usr/local`, it will still mostly use `/etc`, and your `/usr/local/etc` directory will probably be nonexistent, empty, or contain very few files.

On many systems, you can find more information about typical filesystem layout by running `man hier`. If you're using a GNU/Linux system you may be interested in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

#### Where Your System Installs Software

Most of the programs that are part of your system, including programs installed by package managers in the vast majority of GNU/Linux operating systems ([GoboLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoboLinux) being one exception) and some other Unix-like systems, are installed with a prefix of `/usr`. It is rare that you should pass that prefix to `./configure`, because you generally want to avoid conflicts with system-provided software.

`/usr` is permitted to be on a network share or a partition that is otherwise not yet mounted very early in the boot process. Software that must be accessible at this time is usually installed in `/`. That's why both `/usr/bin` and `/bin` exist and why `sh` is usually `/bin/sh`.

#### Package Management

Most package managers have support for installing binaries (though there are exceptions). Usually when you install software in a GNU/Linux system with your package manager, you are installing binary packages. In this case, the package manager doesn't compile anything itself. However, installation still involves copying or extracting files to locations in the filesystem.

This is what I mean when I say your package manager installs most things with a prefix of `/usr`. I do not mean it necessarily runs `./configure --prefix=/usr` or any `./configure` command.

Different operating systems have different package managers. If you're using a distribution like Debian or Ubuntu that is designed for you to use utilities like `dpkg`, `apt-get`, and `aptitude`, then you [should *not* typically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161437/when-would-yum-be-of-use-to-an-ubuntu-user) attempt to install software with `rpm`, `yum`, and `dnf`.

But the core principle is the same across package managers. When a package manager installs a command, it usually goes in a directory that is expected to be in users' `$PATH` environment variables. In GNU/Linux systems the package manager usually manages the *whole* system--except whatever you install yourself in other ways--and thus installs most software with a prefix `/usr`, thereby placing most executable commands in `/usr/bin`. (Of course, like running `make install` or `sudo make install`, package managers usually install other files to other locations as well.)